# отправка данных с формы JavaEE Serlvet Filter

Tags: javascript, java, form, submit

Есть такой блок в `JSP`:

```
<div class="language">
    <span class="lang en" data-lang="en_US">Eng</span>
    <span> | </span>
    <span class="lang ru" data-lang="ru_RU">Рус</span>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="lang" name="lang" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

Есть такой код `JS`:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
    $('div.language form').attr('action', window.location.pathname);
} else {
    $('div.language form').attr('action',window.location.pathname.replace('/',''));
}

$('div.language span.lang').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('input#lang').val($(this).attr('data-lang'));

    $('div.language form').trigger("submit");
});
```

При загрузке страницы `JS`-ом автоматически прописывается `action` на эту же страницу. Проблема в том что после отправки формы, параметра `lang`.

Извлекаю параметры я так: `request.getAttribute("lang")`. Делаю это в Фильтре. Приходит `null`.

В чём может быть проблема?

Пробовал уже и так прописывать `action` - не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения GET/POST-параметров надо использовать

```
request.getParameter("lang")
```

Comment: как так то. как так можно было протупить. Спасибо большое!